# How change background color tooltip primefaces extension?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Hi community I have a problem trying to change the color of tooltip extension, it happens that I'm using PrimeFaces 5.1 and extension 3.0, using the thema of grinders pepper, but does not perform the change in white, I leave my code.

```
<pe:tooltip global="true"  />
```

[image]

```
.ui-tooltip,.ui-tooltip .ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid #9d9d9d;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the PF-ext showcase, there also is a background image. That overrides the color (per css standards). When I tried setting the background image to 'none'

```
.ui-tooltip, .ui-tooltip-content.ui-widget-content {
    background-color: yellow;
    background-image: none;
}
```

in the PF-ext showcase, it worked.